# How to detect the change in HSlider when value is updated

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

Is there a way to detect the value change in HSlider (in Flex 4.0) without touching the slider.

Basically, what I wanted is to detect if the slider value was changed programmatically.
Ex.

```
slider.value += 3; // where slider is a slider component
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT` event is dispatched. Just listen to it.

Comment: You can do that, or add a ChangeWatcher on the value property.  But yeah, event is the better way to go.

Comment: It might be useful to know that the Event.CHANGE event will be fired when the value changes because of a user interaction (like clicking or dragging the thumb).  The FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT event will be fired anytime the value changes regardless if it was changed via user interaction or programmatically.